# Recursively remove all adjacent duplicates

Tags: string, algorithm, stack, time-complexity

Find an algorithm to [recursively remove all adjacent duplicates in a given string](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-remove-adjacent-duplicates-given-string/) this is the original question.I have thought of an algorithm using stacks.

```
1.Initialize a stack  and a char_popped variable
2.Push the first char of str into the stack.
3.now iterate through the characters of string.
if the top of stack matches with the character 
{
pop the character from the stack,
char_popped=character
}
else
{
  if(character==char_popped)
         {DONT DO ANYTHING}
  else
         push the character on the stack
         char_popped=null
}
```

Whatever is remaining on stack is the resultant string.

Auxillary space :O(n)  Complexity : O(n)

Is this a correct solution and canyone explain the o(n) solution explained in the post?

Comment: Why keep `char_popped` when you can just look at the top of the stack? (If checking whether the stack is empty is too painful, then push a sentinel value before you start.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a correct solution

Yes it is. Let me try to sanitize your idea of using stacks taking into account what @rici mentioned.

You want to traverse through the characters of the string **once**. This is how your algorithm flows:

```
 1. Initialize a stack containing the string. (Stack A)
 2. Pop top most element of Stack A and push into Stack B thereby initializing Stack B
 3. Pop from Stack B and pop from Stack A and check if they are equal.
 4. If they aren't push both the elements in Stack B. (The popped element from Stack A is pushed later to preserve order)
 5. Do step 3 till Stack A is empty.

 Stack B should contain the chracters with adjacent duplicates removed.
```

The above algorithm is clearly `O(N)` because at every step 3, we are definitely popping an element off Stack A and therefore the size of Stack A goes down by 1 after every step 3.

> canyone explain the o(n) solution explained in the post?

Coming to the [recursive algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-remove-adjacent-duplicates-given-string/) that you wanted to get a hang on. This is how it goes:

At any point in time the function `removeUtil` has two values - one is the character array `str`
from which we have to remove adjacent duplicates and the other is the character `last_removed`.

Pseudo code with some description -

```
1. It checks if the first two characters of the str are same, if they are:
   update last_removed and call removeUtil again on the remaining characters 
   (hence the str ++)

2. If first two characters are not same, we do the same exercise as in 1
   only this time we start from str[1], hence removeUtil(str+1, last_removed);

3. Now the returned value from call in 2 is stored in a rem_str because we have 
   characters that didn't match like str[0] in 2 that are orphan and need to be appended
   in the final array just like we pushed elements into the stack in your case.

4. Let's assume the string is 'abbac'-

   In the first call we reach here -> removeUtil("bbac", '\0');
   str[0] -> 'a'

   Now this call -> removeUtil("bbac", '\0'); returns "ac"
   and when the recursion unfolds at this point rem_str -> "ac"
   str[0] -> 'a'

   Hence this :
   if (rem_str[0] && rem_str[0] == str[0])
   {
     *last_removed = str[0];
     return (rem_str+1); // In our case this would return "c" to the previous function call
   }

5. if (rem_str[0] == '\0' && *last_removed == str[0])
     return rem_str;

  Consider the string they mention -> "acbbcddc"
  So at some point we have situation where:
    this call happens-> removeUtil("bbcddc", '\0');
    followed by -> removeUtil("cddc", 'b');
    followed by -> removeUtil("ddc", 'b');
    followed by -> removeUtil("c", 'd');
    That returns 'c' and considering the str[0] in the string "cddc" , it goes to case 4
    and therefore 'c' gets removed returning an empty string and last_removed -> 'c'.

  So removeUtil("bbcddc", '\0'); returns an empty string with last_removed -> 'c'.

  However, here str[0] is the same as the last_removed character and therefore should be removed.


6. If none of the following string matches that means str[0] should be appended to final answer.
   rem_str--;
   rem_str[0] = str[0];
   return rem_str;
```

And here also since we are traversing the character array and 'forming' the final character array that get returned by appropriately appending and removing characters, the time complexity is **`O(N)`**.

*Sidenote*- Whenever thinking about recursion, its always easier to think of it like a depth of function calls unfolding and then returning values which then get collected to return the final result.

Anyway, I hope I could clarify myself and hope this gets you started in the right direction.