# Recursively remove all adjacent duplicates(Using stack)

Tags: c++, string, stack

I did it using and also checked previously it's been answered ([Recursively remove all adjacent duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825084/recursively-remove-all-adjacent-duplicates)) using the same logic but when I applied that it's showing the **segmentation fault**! Please help in correcting the code. The link to the question is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-remove-adjacent-duplicates-given-string/

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s,ans;
        cin>>s;
        stack<char>st;
        int n=s.size();
        cout<<n;
        int i=0;
        while(n--)
        {
            char b;
            if(s[i]==st.top())
            {
                b=st.top();
                st.pop();
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            if(s[i]==b)
            {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            st.push(s[i]);
            b='1';
            i++;
        }
        // char a[st.size()];
        int j=0;
        while(!st.empty())
        {
            // a[j]=st.top();
            ans.push_back(st.top());
            // cout<<st.top();
            st.pop();
            j++;
        }
        // cout<<ans<<endl;
    }
    //code
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes I did some changes after that, the link for it is: https://pastebin.com/wY5Ak03g

Comment: 1) "_Yes I did_" If you did, you would know where it occurs, and possibly, why. Please share your findings, that you did, in stepping through the code with a debugger. 2) "_the link for it is_" No. Everything necessary for answering of the question, must be in the question itself.